# Custom Charts in Syncfusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, customization, syncfusion

I am building an application for graphical presentation of my reports, for that I am using syncfusion's chart tools, as I have explored and reviewed all basic functionality of chart tool and also implemented it in my application, but in one situation I am getting some problems, I am sharing my case below:

1. Chart should show multiple data from multiple tables using series, which is already done.
   2 There will be 2 date picker called from and to
   3 from value should be Min value of x axis and to will be max value but in this case I want that if there is date like 24-Oct-2014 and in that my workers has done their work at multiple time then I want that on x axis for 24-Oct-2014 all time should be there on x axis like on 24-Oct-2014 time is 2:00 PM, 5:00 PM etc then these time also be there on x- axis
   and on y axis there will be efficiency 
   so I want that graph will be plotted between the time slots on particular date and efficiency

please let me know if my case is clear, its the case in which I am not getting any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by replacing the range of the chart with the values return from the data picker control.

The below code snippet illustrates this

```
[JS]
$("#container").ejChart("option", { "primaryXAxis": { range: { min: min, max: max } } })
```

In this, where, min and max are the values from the date picker control.
The below code snippet illustrate that how to return selected date from the Syncfusion date picker contol.

```
[JS]
var obj = $("#datepickerinline").ejDatePicker('instance');
var x = obj.option('value')
var min = new Date(x.getFullYear(), x.getDay(), x.getMonth());
```

I have also attached a sample in the below link to illustrate this.
Link:http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/132020/WebApplication12110738610.zip

Note: Kindly refer Synfusion.EJ and Syncfusion.Ej.MVC dll to make it runnable.

Thanks